# Custom Logging and Future Methods

Tags: apex, trigger, future, asynchronous, logging

I have been reading up on the custom logging, DML, and exceptions but haven't seen anything that talks about @Future methods and exceptions.

I have two scenarios:

1. A Button is clicked on a Lead, class A is called (class A has a try/catch with logging), a Webservice class is called, the Webservice fails, an exception is thrown, the exception trickles back up to class A, logging class is called, and a new logging record is inserted.
2. A Lead is inserted, a Trigger is fired, a Webservice is called from a future method, the Webservice fails, an exception is thrown.

   - I want to put logging on the Trigger but because of the future method, the exception does not make it's way back up to the root level. I have found that if I want to log the exception, then I have to put the log on the `future method`. This breaks my pattern of always putting logging on the root level.

Is there a way to push the exception up from a `@future method` to the method or class that calls it? Is there a way to put logging on the root class in all scenarios even if there is a `@future method` involved?

```
trigger AllLeadTrigger on Lead (before insert, before update, before delete, after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
    if( Trigger.isInsert ){
        if(Trigger.isBefore) {
            ...
        }else {
             ...
        }
    }else if (Trigger.isUpdate ) {
        if(Trigger.isBefore) {
            ...
        }else {
           try{
               LeadEncryptedEmailStringCreation les = new LeadEncryptedEmailStringCreation();
               les.leadEncryptedEmailStringCreate(Trigger.newMap, Trigger.oldMap);
           }catch(Exception ex){
               NFLogger.logError('AllLeadTrigger, LeadEncryptedEmailStringCreation, trigger', 'Call to leadEncryptedEmailStringCreate failed.', ex);
           }
       }
   }
}


public with sharing class LeadEncryptedEmailStringCreation {
    public void leadEncryptedEmailStringCreate(Map<Id, Lead> newLeads, Map<Id, Lead> oldLeads) {
        List<Id> leadIDList = new List<Id>();
        try {
            for (Lead l : [SELECT Id, pi__url__c, IsConverted, Web_Id_NatFund__c, Encrypted_Email_String__c FROM Lead
                            WHERE Id IN :newLeads.keySet() AND pi__url__c != NULL AND IsConverted = FALSE AND Web_Id_NatFund__c != NULL
                                AND Encrypted_Email_String__c = NULL]) {
                if (l.pi__url__c != oldLeads.get(l.id).pi__url__c) {
                    leadIDList.add(l.Id);
                }
            }
            if (leadIDList.size() > 0) {
                updateEncryptedEmailStringForLeads(leadIDList);
             }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @Future(callout=true)
    public static void updateEncryptedEmailStringForLeads(List<Id> leadIdList) {
        try {
            Map<String, String> idAndTokenMap = new Map<String, String>();
            List<Lead> leadListUpdate = new List<Lead>();
            TokenGenerator tg = new TokenGenerator();
            idAndTokenMap = tg.getTokenizedPayloadForBulkLeads(leadIdList); //webservice is called here
            for (String leadId : idAndTokenMap.keySet()) {
                Lead l = new Lead(Id = leadId, Encrypted_Email_String__c = idAndTokenMap.get(leadId));
                leadListUpdate.add(l);
            }
            update leadListUpdate;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            //throw e //this does persist upwards so I log here
            NFLogger.logError('LeadEncryptedEmailStringCreation, tokenizer', 'There has been an error in the updateEncryptedEmailStringForLeads on Lead(s): ' + leadIdList, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The future method simply hasn't executed yet by the time the caller completes.

Maybe what you could do is pass an identifier from the calling class to the future method. The future method passes this into the custom logger which locates the same log entry that was used for the caller and appends to it.

Comment: More to the point, the future method is even guaranteed *not* to execute before the caller finishes, so it can be rolled back if anything cancels it.

Comment: Interesting. Good approach, I will look into implementing something along those lines. Another thought is, I could change my pattern to put loggers on the class level vs the trigger. This way I can put the logger directly on the future method if applicable.